# DataGrid ItemsSource Cell value changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, dependency-properties, itemssource

I have a custom data grid, the datagrid display a collection of coordiantes:

```
<customControls:CustomDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"              
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"      
              CanUserAddRows="True" SelectionMode="Extended" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
    <DataGrid.Columns>                                                                         
      <DataGridTextColumn  Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}" Width="Auto"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}" Width="Auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>   
</customControls:CustomDataGrid >
```

I need a way to get notified when a cell value has changed (not a row change).

Answer (score 1):

If you binded observable collection in datagrid. 
Use Points.Collectionchanged Event, i think is good for you.

Comment: Tried it, the event is not firing.